# Bash printf with empty columns

Tags: bash, printf

Any idea how I can still include empty space in a row using printf ie when the column variable is empty? For example:

```
printf $GREEN"################################ SOURCED ###############################"$RESET
printf $GREEN'%-1s%-15s%-60s%-1s%s\n' '#'$RESET ' REGION NAME:' $OS_REGION_NAME $GREEN'#'$RESET
printf $GREEN"########################################################################"$RESET
```

Basically I am creating a box with that shows sourced variables. Sometimes some of the fields are empty. The box shouldn't collapse on the right when this happens. I thought I had this down correctly with my column settings on that middle line, but apparently it ignores the width if the column is empty.

The output should look something like this:

```
################################ SOURCED ###############################
# AUTH URL: blah blah blah                                             #
# REGION NAME: fcdnjcndkjcndkajcndkjcnklcnklsncklsnkcldnslc            #
########################################################################
```

but it ends up looking like this

```
################################ SOURCED ###############################
# AUTH URL: blah blah blah #
# REGION NAME: fcdnjcndkjcndkajcndkjcnklcnklsncklsnkcldnslc #
########################################################################
```

***SOLUTION***

The solution was to put the variables inside double quotes. Such a simple fix...

```
printf $GREEN'%-1s%-15s%-55s%-1s%s\n' '#'$RESET ' REGION NAME:' "$OS_REGION_NAME" $GREEN'#'$RESET
```

***NOTE***

The $GREEN and $RESET was for coloring set in another part of script.

Comment: Quote your variable expansions. If `$OS_REGION_NAME` is empty then the variable value is the empty string and the command becomes `printf format '#reset' 'green#reset'` i.e. you lose an argment.

Comment: Well that fixes the printf issue, but breaks the variables

Comment: Also there's no reason to use your `$GREEN` and `$RESET` variables in the format string on the first and third lines and no reason to use double quotes on those lines either (not that they hurt anything either).

Comment: The single quotes were example not literal (that's why I used `green` and `reset` and not `$GREEN` and `$RESET`. Use double quotes around any variable expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you failed to quote the expansion of `$OS_REGION_NAME` so when it is the empty string that entire argument to `printf` disappears (i.e. `printf` sees one fewer argument and everything after it slides up in the format string specifiers).

That being said I would also rewrite your lines this way

```
printf '################################ SOURCED ###############################\n' "$GREEN" "$RESET"
printf '$s%-1s%-15s%-60s%-1s%s\n' "$GREEN" "#$RESET" ' REGION NAME:' "$OS_REGION_NAME" "$GREEN#$RESET"
printf '%s########################################################################%s\n' "$GREEN" "$RESET"
```